# Flutter change theme from a sub widget navigates back to home screen

Tags: flutter, themes

I have a "settings" page in my app that is not the home screen set on home: on the materialApp. I want to push a button on that page for the dark/light/system themes, and the app will change the theme without the app rebuilding and going back to the home: screen() on the root materialApp.

Currently, the theme will change just fine; however, the change causes the app to go all the way back to the home: screen() instead of staying on the "settings" page. Anything to point me in the right direction on how to make a theme change button on a page other than your home: screen() and not rebuild the entire app back to that screen from a "settings" page.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this!